# Setting up Intel Wireless AC 3160 NIC in FreeBSD

Tags: terminal, drivers, freebsd

I have a pretty frustrating issue with FreeBSD. I am a Linux user who decided to switch to FreeBSD because I liked the idea of the ports system that it uses. I decided to give it a try in a virtual machine on Linux Mint and it ran flawlessly (I had to setup the gui but the process was trivial) so I decided I'd try a switch from Linux Mint to FreeBSD on my physical machine... Well it turns out setting up FreeBSD on my physical machine is not as smooth of a process. The ifconfig command is not showing a wlan0 wireless interface, and FreeBSD is not able to detect my network card (an Intel Wireless AC 3160) through the dmesg command. I discovered FreeBSD 11.0 supports drivers for the Intel Wireless AC 3160 through the iwm driver, but since I am new to FreeBSD I am not sure how to setup this driver as well as the wlan0 interface to successfully use my network card. Any help to this problem or even just a link to the relevant information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `iwm` driver is not in the GENERIC kernel. The man page `man iwm` specifies the methods required to pull the driver in. Either:

- build a custom kernel
- load at boot time with `/boot/loader.conf`
- load at runtime with `kldload`

The man page does not appear to be online - but it is in the latest snapshot.

Comment: it is described [here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=iwm).